# What GUI technology to use for C# game application?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering what is the best way to go on this one. My intention is to better learn C# by making a game and an appropriate GUI.

My game would have been  something like ZooTycoon (http://www.gamespot.com/zoo-tycoon/)
but much more simple. 
 As I really don't intend to learn a new language (like DirectX) only to write GUI for this application I would prefer something simpler but handy. Does that even exist?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. This site's focus is questions with mostly objective answers. This question is asking for opinions on game engines.

Comment: Well, it is not game engine if I can do it with WinForms or similar technologies

Comment: Take a peek around: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com Many questions like yours there.

Comment: As a broad answer, look into Microsoft's XNA framework.

Comment: @CharlieKilian XNA is dead - might want to look at SharpDX or SlimDX instead.

Comment: Mono game might be worth a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](https://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/).